# OpenDS login password recover

Tags: opendj, opends

I am unable to login into OpenDs server through user cn=administrator and password=*********. I have tried multiple times but authentication not happening. I would like to know if i can reset root's (cn=administrator) password.

Thanks,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the administrators' password can be reset. The server must be stopped to do so. And it is done directly in the configuration file.